# Dynamic graphql schema from json object

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, hotchocolate

I am working on a multi-tenant SAAS application using efcore and graphql using hot chocolate as graphql server, where each tenant can define some custom fields/columns.

For instance, a tenant can add a column Email in customer entity, while another tenant can add another column like Phone in customer entity. On database side, the Customer table will have a pre-defined schema and an extra column named CustomFields. The CustomField column will have jsonb data-type (postgres database) and will store the extra columns added by tenant in json object.

Tenant1 -> Customer.CustomField
{"Email": "xxx@.com"}

Tenant2 -> Customer.CustomField
{"Phone": "xxx-xxx-xxxx"}

The json document can contain any number of properties. My objective is to expose these properties as individual fields in GraphQL schema.

I reviewed [extending-types](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/extending-types), and tried to read the json document and dynamically create the new fields and append to Customer type. However, I can't make it work and dynamically add new dynamic properties as .

At this point not sure which of the following or any of these can be used

1. Dynamic schema
2. Schema Stiching
3. Extended types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer here to my own question so that anyone else having a similar issue can possibly find a reference.

The solution that worked for me is the Dynamic schema feature in version 13.

Extended Types or Type extensions only allow adding/altering types statically during the schema building process. They will be helpful in scenarios like having more than one source for a schema and we want to stitch them without changing the definition of base object. But once a graphql schema is created, it's immutable.

Dynamic types allow raising TypeChanged events to re-load or recreate schema and phase out the previous schema in a safe manner.

Reference from Hot chocolate updated documentation https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/dynamic-schemas

Comment: Hi @Krishna Sarthi I'm facing the same issue and I can't quite add a dynamic field to my entity. I got error `Method not found: 'HotChocolate.Types.Descriptors.TypeReference HotChocolate.Types.Descriptors.TypeInspectorExtensions.GetOutputTypeRef(HotChocolate.Types.Descriptors.ITypeInspector, System.Type)'. (HotChocolate.Types.Pa
gination.CollectionSegmentType)`. Can you provide a working example with your existing model and the code you used to add a dynamic field to this entity (corresponding to an existing column in bdd). Thank you